# How to launch an std::async thread from within an std::async thread and let the first one die once the second is launched?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

What I am trying to achieve is having and autonomous async thread mill, were async A does its task, launches async B and dies. async B does the same in repeat.

Example code: main.cpp

```
class operation_manager : public std::enable_shared_from_this<operation_manager> {
public:
    operation_manager() {}
    void do_operation(void) {
        std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<operation_manager>)> fun( [this](std::shared_ptr<operation_manager> a_ptr) {
            if( a_ptr != nullptr ) {
                a_ptr->do_print();
            }
        } );
        i_ap.read(fun, shared_from_this());
    }

    void do_print(void) {
        std::cout << "Hello world\n" << std::flush;
        do_operation();
    }

private:
    async_operation i_ap;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto om( std::make_shared<operation_manager>() );
    om->do_operation();
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example code: async_operation.hpp

```
class async_operation {
public:
    async_operation() {};

    template<typename T>
    void read(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<T>)> a_callback, std::shared_ptr<T> a_ptr) {
        auto result( std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
            wait();
            a_callback(a_ptr);
            return true;
        }) );
        result.get();
    }

private:
    void wait(void) const {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
};
```

Comment: Re, "What I am trying to achieve is..." There's no question there. What happened when you tried to compile and run your code? What is it that you not understand about what happened?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thats why I provided the code, for people who understand async to see what is going wrong with it. Every time a new async thread launches the one that launched it stays on wait() until the the new one is finished, but the new one will also launch an async so threads and threads just keep waiting.  Helpful comment mate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is calling `result.get()` inside the async task - that causes it to block and wait for the next task to finish. wait you need to do is save the futures somewhere, and let them run.

Here is the modified code to the async_operation class:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::future<bool>>> results;

class async_operation {
public:
    async_operation() {};

    template<typename T>
    void read(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<T>)> a_callback, std::shared_ptr<T> a_ptr) {

        results.push_back(std::make_shared<std::future<bool>>(std::async(std::launch::async, [=]() {
            wait();
            a_callback(a_ptr);
            return true;
        })));
    }

private:
    void wait(void) const {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that I canged the capture from [&] to [=] because you want to capture the actual std::function and not a reference to it, because it will go out of context when the function exits and you'll get a segmentation fault

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. Where would be the best place to destroy the results though? Because I don't actually need them.